# Having some issue with show and hide. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Form:

```
<form  name="test" action="" method="post">
    Day And Time Available:<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" id="day1" value="monday" onclick="show();"/>Monday<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" id="day2" value="Tuesday" onclick="show();"/>Tuesday<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" id="day3" value="Wednesday" onclick="show();"/>Wednesday<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" id="day4" value="Thursday" onclick="show();"/>Thursday<br/>
</form>

<p style="visibility:hidden" id="timing">Here I am maintain the form</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return valid();"/>
</form>
```

If user have have selected Monday, tuesday I want output like this:

```
Monday
From Time
<select name="Fromtime" id="Fromtime">
    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
</select>
To Time
<select name="Totime" id="Totime">
    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
</select>

Tuesday:
From Time
<select name="Fromtime" id="Fromtime">
    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
</select>
To Time
<select name="Totime" id="Totime">
    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
</select>
```

1. How do I solve this in jQuery. Based on user Selection I want to show the day and timing form.
2. Likewise if the user selects Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday how do I show the day and timing form

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function show() 
{
var flag = 0;
for (var i = 1; i< 7; i++) 
{
if(document.getElementById("day"+i).checked)
{
document.getElementById('Fromtime').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('Totime').style.visibility='visible';
}
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: seems you have an invalid markup. like same ids for multiple checkboxes like `id="day"` and `FromTime, ToTime`.

Comment: forgot the id="day" how to solve this.I am struggling to solve this . I need answer in query or java script. How to solve this in problem. I have given my code.

Comment: please see the question I have given my js code

Comment: I have added some code in javascript can help me further?

Comment: Do you have multiple from time and to time form for each day i.e. for Monday, tuesday and so on???

Comment: NO  only one time form for all days what I have listed in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jai mentions, there are a couple of issues with your HTML. First, you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, e.g: your 'Fromtime' and 'Totime' select boxes.

All the data you wish to submit needs to be wrapped in `<form>` tags. It looks like you've got one too many closing tags here which will cause problems.

That being said, you can achieve the show/hide effect with something like the following (I've stayed away from jQuery for something this simple):

```js
function show(element) {
  var day = element.value; // gets the value of checkbox, e.g: 'monday'
  var timeElement = document.querySelector('.times-' + day); // finds correct times- element for day
  
  if (element.checked) {
    timeElement.style.display = 'block';  
  } else {
    timeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form  name="test" action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Day And Time Available:</legend>  
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="monday" onclick="show(this);"/>Monday<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="tuesday" onclick="show(this);"/>Tuesday<br/>
  </fieldset>


  <div class="times-monday hidden">
    <p>Monday</p>
    <label for="FromtimeMonday">From Time</label>
    <select name="FromtimeMonday" id="FromtimeMonday">
      <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
      <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
      <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
    </select>

    <label for="TotimeMonday">To Time</label>
    <select name="TotimeMonday" id="TotimeMonday">
      <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
      <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
      <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
    </select>  
  </div>

  <div class="times-tuesday hidden">
    <p>Tuesday</p>
    <label for="FromtimeTueday">From Time</label>
    <select name="FromtimeTueday" id="FromtimeTueday">
      <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
      <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
      <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
    </select>

    <label for="TotimeTueday">To Time</label>
    <select name="TotimeTueday" id="TotimeTueday">
      <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
      <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
      <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
    </select>  
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" text="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks lot. why can't we keep the timing form has one form.because Here we are giving seven time .I thing you got my question.for this logic shall we need to do like this or depends upon the person.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, are you wanting to use more than one form?

Comment: no. we show timing form for days.any how timing form is common for all days .assume I chosen day monday,tuesday. you are chosen monday,tuesday,wednesday. according to user needs we show from time and to time. for that I am asking. here we need to give seven times. timing form.